# android monkey restart apps automaticlly

Tags: android, application-restart, monkey

I'm a little new in android monkey testing, so please forgive me if I'm going to ask some noob thing:) 
 I'm lunching the monkey with

```
monkey -throttle 10 -p com.mypackage.bla -v 5000
```

Everything okay, the monkey runs perfectly a lot of GUI event has been generated, but sometimes the application get restarted. Yes,yes... I see my splash screen again.
I had checked the logcat and the monkey log but I didn't found any error message or something.
 Can anybody tell me why should I got my app restarted ?

Thank you so much,
Károly

Answer (score 1):

Because of this flag set it to 0
--pct-appswitch 
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html